# Angular - Unable to get service to get a successful HTTP request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building a basic application to load a list of incidents currently ongoing. I had a basic CRUD system where I had built all my functions in the controller. I was recommended to use Angular custom services instead of piling on many functions on the controller .

I am now reworking my code into a custom service but cant quite grasp the structure. Below is what I had so far, but at the moment I am getting the error `Unexpected token .` on my Service code on this line `var configurations.data_result_1 = configurations.data_result_1.split("\r\n");`

I get a feeling that my code is all wrong but cant quite find similar situations online to base myself on. Would appreciate some help. Here is what I got so far:

Service:

```
var GDI_configurations = {};

app.service('MyService', function () {
    this.sayHello() //fetch data on page load.

    this.sayHello = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    $http({
        method: 'GET',  
        url: 'AJAX PATH',
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"} 
    }).then(function(data){

      var configurations = data;
      var configurations.data_result_1 = configurations.data_result_1.split("\r\n");
      var configurations.data_result_2 = configurations.data_result_2.split("\r\n");

  };
});
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('AppController', function (MyService, $scope) {
 $scope.configurations = function() { MyService.sayHello() }; 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all you are not injecting $q and $http in the service.
Second of all you are not using $q to resolve or reject.
Third it is $q redundant to create a promise from $q since the $http service returns a promise.

please consider the following code :

```
    app.service('MyService', function ($http) {

        this.sayHello = function () {
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',  
                url: 'AJAX PATH',
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose;charset=utf-8"} 
            });
        };
    });



    app.controller('AppController', function (MyService, $scope) {
        $scope.configurations = null;
        MyService.sayHello().then(function(data){
            $scope.configuration = data;
           $scope.configurations.data_result_1 = $scope.configurations.data_result_1.split("\r\n");
           $scope.configurations.data_result_2  = $scope.configurations.data_result_2.split("\r\n");
        }, function(error){
           // some error occurred
        })
    });
```

if you want to cache the response inside the service to retrieve it from multiple controllers please let me know.. i can rewrite the code in such way.. hope this helps you.. cheers

Comment: Hi Adrian thanks for the quick response, I only need to call the service function only once (upon page load) and cache it to reuse it in my controller. How would you aproach it in that sense?